# How do I print out multiple Divs with Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically have this markup:

```
<div id="box">
 <div id="id_1></div>
 <div id="id_2></div>
 <div id="id_3></div>
 <div id="id_4></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is have Jquery or javascript print out the different divs with different id numbers, please, how would I go about doing this? I'm mostly a PHP guy and this is one of the last things in my project that is holding me back really bad... please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by having it "print out the different divs"? Your question isn't very clear as written...

Comment: document.getELementById('box').childNodes

Comment: start with http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $('#box').append("<div id='id_" + (i + 1) + "'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code,  you should probably read up on jQuery to understand how it works.

```
$(function() {
  var box = $('#box');
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    box.append('<div id="id_' + i + '">' + i + '</div>');
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JlAffVadhKiW6HnbWqNx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Create a new HTML element in jQuery using `$()`. See the snippet below:

```js
var parent = $("<div id='box'>outer div</div>");

for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  var child = $("<div id='id_"+ i + "'>inner div</div>");
  parent.append(child);
}

$("body").append(parent);
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

div div{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Relevant Documentation with Examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = $('#box'),
    html = '',
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
   html += '<div id="id_' + (i + 1) + '"></div>';
}

box.append(html);
```

The other answers suggest calling `append` in each iteration of the loop. Don't do that, it will likely be bad for performance. If you must do this with jQuery, you want to minimize DOM manipulation as much as possible.